# The button and the navigation is off in mobile version of the website

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

How do i make the navigation adapt to different screens?

If you require, i could post certain bits of my code.

The problem is, i am not sure where to begin

[image]

Comment: How we can provide solution if you are not posting your code here ?

Comment: There is a lot of code. I clearly state that i will immediately update my question with the code.

Comment: @chuckfinley Yea, it would be helpful if you included your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use specific CSS for small devices (it's called mediaqueries) : e.g. for screen smaller than 768px

```
/* normal screens */
.nav-button {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
  }
.nav-button span{
    font-size:12px;
}

/* small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-button {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
  }
  .nav-button span{
    display:none;
  }
}
```